# Native javascript decompress function in Chrome/webkit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, compression

If you are sending data that is base64-encoded and compressed (using, say, python's zlib.compress()), you can use the native Chrome function window.atob() to convert from base64 to binary data. Is there any similar native javascript function to decompress the zlib-compressed data? Is there some hack to do this?

I know that code to decompress data is already in the browser because it can receive HTML sent with gzip headers.

I am not looking for a javascript library to do decompression.

If you come up a decompression scheme on the browser, I can compress it in that format for transmission. In other words, any decompression routine is acceptable.

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for "btoa()", but for the record base64 encoding is *not* compression; in fact it makes the data bigger.

Comment: Okay, I guess I was unclear. I am not looking for btoa(). I know about that. I am talking about decompressing data compressed with LZ77 or LZW or gzip or any similar compression algorithm.

Comment: That's what I suspected :-)  Unfortunately I don't know of an API that exposes that, but I'm not familiar with non-standard browser internals, especially for Chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 2020 Update

#### Chrome 80+ supports `CompressionStream` and `DecompressionStream` APIs

Gzip-compress a stream

```js
const compressedReadableStream = inputReadableStream.pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));
```

Deflate-compress an ArrayBuffer

```js
function compressArrayBuffer(input) {
  const stream = new Response(input).body
    .pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('deflate'));
  return new Response(stream).arrayBuffer();
}
```

Gzip-decompress a Blob to a Blob

This treats the input as a gzip file regardless of the mime-type. The output Blob has an empty mime-type.

```js
async function DecompressBlob(blob) {
  const ds = new DecompressionStream('gzip');
  const decompressedStream = blob.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
  return await new Response(decompressedStream).blob();
}
```

https://github.com/WICG/compression/blob/master/explainer.md

Comment: Awesome. Only 9 years after I asked the question -- so long ago that I can't remember why I wanted this. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a hack to paint a PNG containing compressed data into a `canvas` and reading the data back, pixel by pixel: [Compression using Canvas and PNG-embedded data](https://web.archive.org/web/20090220141811/http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/compression-using-canvas-and-png.html). If you want anything that uses a browser's native compression library, here's one option. Unfortuantely, you have to convert the `ImageData` to string within javascript.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such function exposed.

Comment: Okay, and how do you know that? How might I become convinced of this?

Comment: By looking at the publicly-exposed global APIs provided by each browser, e.g. in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

Try [window.btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa).

Comment: I am not looking for the inverse of atob. A common com,position is to take data, compress it with LZ77 or similar algorithm, base64 encode it, and transmit it to the client where the client undoes the base64 encoding and then decompresses the data. Undoing the base64 encoding can be done natively with atob. What native function, if any, can undo the compression?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't expand on "sending" but if the server sets `Content-Encoding: gzip` then the browser should decompress it before passing the resulting content to JavaScript.